# How to set table height of parent div with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 and I have a `div` wrapping my `table` with the class `table-responsive`. In my CSS file, I have set the `.table-responsive` `height` to be `100%` assuming it would take up the total height of the parent `div`. However, it is overflowing the `div` and when I set the `height` to a fixed definition of `300px` for example, the table becomes responsive and has the vertical scroll-bars but of course, if I change the viewport height or the size of the browser it doesn't respond dynamically. So on mobile devices, it still overflows.

I am currently generating my tables dynamically in JS and it looks something like this:

```
function populatePersonnelTable(data) {
    var directoryDiv = $("<div></div>").addClass("table-responsive").appendTo('#nav-personnel');
    var companyDirectoryPersonnel = $("<table></table>").attr("id", "companyDirectoryPersonnel").addClass("table table-striped table-hover").appendTo(directoryDiv);
    var directoryHead = $("<thead></thead>").appendTo(companyDirectoryPersonnel);
    var directoryBody = $("<tbody></tbody>").appendTo(companyDirectoryPersonnel);
    $('#companyDirectoryPersonnel tbody').empty();

    var directoryResult = data;

    $("<th></th>").text("Full Name").appendTo(directoryHead);
    $("<th></th>").text("Location").appendTo(directoryHead);
    $("<th></th>").text("Department").appendTo(directoryHead);
    $("<th></th>").text("Edit").appendTo(directoryHead);
    $("<th></th>").text("Delete").appendTo(directoryHead);

    directoryResult.forEach(function (entry){

     ... // GENERATING ROWS //
```

I did originally have the `<table>` and `<thead>` already written in the HTML file but decided to also generate them dynamically just in case there were any strange DOM errors.

Here is my HTML document for class references:

```
<body>

        <div class="container custom flex-column">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col m-auto p-3"><h1 class="text-center">Company Directory</h1></div>
            </div>

            <div class="flex-row p-3 mb-2" id="searchAndGo">
                <div class="col flex-fill btn-group-sm">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="searchQuery" size="20" placeholder="Search Names">
                        <select id="locations" class="_locations">
                        </select>
                        <select id="departments" class="_departments">
                        </select>
                        <div class="float-end btn-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-success" id="startSearch" onclick="startSearch()">GO</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="resetAll()">Reset</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                </div> 
                <div class="flex-row text-center">
                    <div class="dropdown" id="dropDownContainer">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Advanced Settings
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2" id="radioSelect">
                            <li><span class="dropdown-item-text">Search by:</span></li>
                            <li><span class="dropdown-item"><input class="custom-control-input" id="any" type="radio" value="any" name="name" checked><label for="any">Any</label></span></li>                           
                            <li><span class="dropdown-item"><input class="custom-control-input" id="forename" type="radio" value="forename" name="name"><label for="forename">Forename</label></span></li>                           
                            <li><span class="dropdown-item"><input class="custom-control-input" id="surname" type="radio" value="surname" name="name"><label for="surname">Surname</label></span></li>                       
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <nav>
                <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                  <a class="nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#nav-personnel" role="tab">Personnel</a>
                  <a class="nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#nav-departments" role="tab">Departments</a>
                  <a class="nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#nav-locations" role="tab">Locations</a>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div class="tab-content container p-3" id="myTabContent">
                
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-personnel" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="personnel-tab">

                    <button id="addEntry" class="btn btn-success" onclick="openAddModal()">Add Personnel</button>

                </div>
```

This is the current CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #85daf1;
    height: 100vh;
}

.custom {
    background-color: hsl(47, 100%, 93%);
    height: 100%;
}

.table-responsive {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

[image]

When I set a fixed `height` like `300px` this is what it looks like:

[image]

`.custom` is the yellow-y colour main content div. why does my responsive table insist on overflowing? If I set `overflow: hidden` then none of the content is accessible as no scroll bar generates.

Here is a view of the dev-tools panel:
[image]

I have also tried changing the `#myTabContents` CSS height to `100%` and a fixed height in pixels, but that still overflowed, it's as if it's getting `height: 100%` as the exact height in pixels of the parent div `height` and not taking up to 100% of it's `height` and fitting in it.